# get operation in fabric to use hostname

Tags: fabric

I am pretty new to fabric and trying to setup a deployment in the below fashion:

```
Main repo --> Local_repo -> Deployment server
```

I want to
(1)push the build from the main repo to the local repo
(2)Deployment server needs to pull the available code from the local repo

I did the first step sucessfully using put but then I am not able to 2nd step using get operation.
I tried using git pull but then I get an error stating its not a git repo and same goes for hg pull as well.
Is there a way where we can combine get operation with the host name: for ex:

`get ('username@localrepo/local_repo_build_path', deployment_server_local_path)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a git pull, you have to most likely use the context managers cd/lcd to move into the directory of the repo. Also you can't specify the username/host like that. It's set in the @host or @role definition for the task, and it'll pick that up automatically, though also it's not going to pull down a full dir, you'd need to use the contrib rsync for something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Morgan!!! I tried using rsync and set this up successfully!

Cheers :)